# Pyinstaller: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, pyinstaller, filenotfounderror

I have been trying to export a python file as an exacutable file using ptinstaller.  However, I get the following error:

"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\pyinstaller\bincache00_py310_64bit\python310.dll'.

So I understand that the system cannot find this file at the given directory, but how do I fix it? The command I entered in the prompt is as follows:
pyinstaller --onefile -w name.py

I have tried uninstalling python and reinstalling it, but this didn't work.  I need the program to export my file as an exacutable.

If you know how I can fix this, please let me know.

Comment: Pyinstaller tries to build the exe with `python3.10`. What version of python do you have installed? (Type `python --version` in terminal.)

Comment: The lastest version